# Word text highlight color

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following vba code removes all 'text highlight colors' from a word document, but i only want 'pink highlight' to be removed, leaving out other highlight colors untouched. Any help, dear members, would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub HighlightRemoveAllPink()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = wdColorPink
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = 0
    With Selection.Find
        .text = ""
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


End Sub
```

Comment: I borrowed `.ClearFormatting` and `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` from here as the main trick in another puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Selection.Find.Highlight` expects boolean, so:

```
Selection.Find.Highlight = True
```

To remove specific color, I used this code:

```
With Selection.Find
  .Highlight = True
  Do While (.Execute(Forward:=True) = True) = True
    If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdColorPink Then
       Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
  Loop
End With
```

Comment: not working. and this is text highlight, not 'font color' .

Comment: thanks bro, but not working again. can u re-check at ur end and place your replaced code within mine, and let me .  appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: In my case, I did not need the `(Forward:=True)` to get it done for anything after the selection.